# ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I get that message every time when trying to install zapier-cli.
Can someone help me with solving the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 64):

I think you need to manually install **ajv** or update it to version 6 if you already have a lower version installed

```
npm i ajv
```

I had a similar issue so I installed it manually and everything worked for me

Answer (score 18):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. It looks like this is a bug with [npm itself](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/708#issuecomment-377696889). Updating npm (`npm i -g npm`) or manually installing ajv (`npm i -g ajv@6`) should resolve the warning.

Comment: npm 6.2.0 does not issue an error message the first time (when no `node_modules` is present) but if you run `npm install` again, the message appears.

Comment: Doesn't work. This has been around since May, and no resolution? How do we remove it completly?

Comment: `npm i ajv@6 --save-dev` might be what you want? `-g` installs it globally.

Comment: `zapier-platform-cli` is installed globally, so its missing dependencies should be as well.

Comment: Hi, will not updating it to this version break the build?

Answer (score 10):

Problems: npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed.
You must install peer dependencies by yourself.
You missed the dependencies of `ajv@^6.0.0`
Just install it :

```
npm install ajv@^6.0.0
```